# Winrt app - navigate to another application

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm developing **winrt (or windows store) application**. I would like to **navigate to another (installed) application**, but I didn't find solution for it. E.g. I have twitter section with tweets and after clicking on some tweet user should be redirected to **windows store twitter application** directly to clicked tweet. I read [How to launch the default app for a URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779672.aspx) but there is not what I need. Do you have some experience with this issue please?

Comment: I believe you can only directly launch into another app if they have a `protocol` declared, which is up to the other developer. You may be able to launch into it using the package name/id, but I am unsure how to do that, and your app will break if it ever changes. Not only that, but there are multiple possible twitter applications, so assuming which twitter application the user has installed/uses is unlikely to be feasible. I think there may be a better method for doing what you desire. Do you want to allow them to post to twitter? If so, why not use the Twitter API?

Comment: Thank you for input. Yes, you're right. User can have plenty of twitter app types and it should be defined to which app user will be redirected. If app is not found, user could be redirected to store or to web browser to twitter page. No, I don't want to allow user post from my app, only redirecting. I have to explore more possibilities.

Comment: If that's what is necessary, then you have to rely upon the twitter app for accepting those kind of links. They don't accept it by default, just as your app does not accept them by default. If the app has a `protocol` declared for it then you can access it via something like `twitter://query`. But again, the developer of the other app has to create that protocol.